# How create a new instance of a class that is present inside another class?

Tags: c#, class

I want create a new instance of a class that is present inside another class and access yours member.

Based on code below i want create a list of clients connected in my server desktop application.

Then i tried the following code but says that "Command" class not is acessible.

How i can fix this?

**Client.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class Client
{
    public class Command
    {
        public Socket sock;
        public Guid ID;
        public string RemoteAddress;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

        public Command(Socket sock)
        {
            this.sock = sock;
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            RemoteAddress = sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        }

        public void Send(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            sock.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback((ar) =>
            {
                sock.EndSend(ar);
            }), buffer);
        }
    }

    public class Screenshot
    {
        public Socket sock;
        public Guid ID;
        public string RemoteAddress;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

        public Screenshot(Socket sock)
        {
            this.sock = sock;
            ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            RemoteAddress = sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        }

        public void Send(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            sock.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback((ar) =>
            {
                sock.EndSend(ar);
            }), buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

And in other class i tried:

```
class Listener
{

Socket s;
public List<Command> clients; // not accessible "Command"

public Listener()
{
    clients = new List<Client>();
    s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}

public void BeginListen(int port)
{
    s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
    s.Listen(100);
    s.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), s);
}

void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket sock = handler.EndAccept(ar);
    Command client = new Command(sock); // not accessible "Command"
    clients.Add(client);

    sock.BeginReceive(client.buffer, 0, client.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), client);
    handler.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), handler);
}
```

Comment: Since it is inside of the `Client` class, you have to reference it using `Client.Command`

Comment: @clcto, thank you. Working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `List<Command>` to point a new instance type is `List<Client>` because `Client` is different with `Command` class, It is a inside of class.

```
public List<Command> clients; // not accessible "Command"

public Listener()
{
    clients = new List<Client>();
    s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}
```

try to use `Client.Command` instead of `Command` or `Client`

```
public List<Client.Command> clients; 

public Listener()
{
    clients = new List<Client.Command>();
    s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}
```